# files not indexed but never deleted in the working directory with git?

Tags: git, file, branch

In different projects, I always have a couple of files that I don't want to index, but never want them to delete either !
ex. ideas in text files, helper files for the IDE, etc..
they may contain somewhat confidential information, so I really don't want to put them in the index.

When I make a `git checkout newbranch` these files are not in the branch so they will be deleted and I cannot bring them back, because I don't have them in any other place.

How can I have these files never deleted ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Add them to .gitignore](http://book.git-scm.com/4_ignoring_files.html)

by the way, that's a link, it explains everything.

Comment: Please upvote and check the answer if my answer solved your problem. And remember to google! XD

Comment: The fun part is that I already used this feature, but never realized it works this way :D I tought the excluded files will never be in the index, but they really never deleted either !

Comment: If you use a gui, this becomes a lot easier. I should point you in the direction of SourceTree if you're on mac, idk what if you're on windows, and search the repo if you're on linux. I'm glad that helped.

Comment: wow, sourcetree is far more better than gitX which I used so far, thanks for the tip!